# CSS hover state issue when adding letter spacing on a 90deg text

Tags: html, css

When I hover the `p` tag and add a `letter-spacing` on it, it messes up the entire text. I wanted to hover it and it stays in the same position with the letter-spacing on it.

```css
#text {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#text:hover {
  letter-spacing: 10px
}
```

```html
<p id="text">sample text rotation</p>
```

Comment: that's the expected behavior. It's unclear without knowing your intend

Comment: I edited it, I wanted to stay the text in the same position when I hovered on it.

Comment: I think the reason why it moves is because it becomes a two line text. Reducing the text size or increasing the p div dimensions should solve you problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `white-space: nowrap`

BTW, your second `transform` rewrites the first one.
The correct use is `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);`

```css
#text {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#text:hover {
  letter-spacing: 10px
}
```

```html
<p id="text">sample text rotation</p>
```

Comment: this my friend is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The flickering happens because the `transform-origin` is wrong. You're rotating the text, so you should take the *original* transform-origin into account (which is from `left` to right).

See this updated code snippet for the result.

```css
.text {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top left;
  left: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.text:hover {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">sample text rotation</p>
```

Comment: Well, It helps but now the first letter is not moving like the default behavior, what I mean is could it be like the letter is expanding. I don't know if I making any sense but did you get my point? :)

Comment: @KevinNisay I updated the answer, I hope that I get what you're saying: first letter stays in position.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already resolved the issue. Thank you. @Roy

Comment: No worries, @KevinNisay

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things:

- You have 2 transform tags on your css
- You still will need more spacing padding so the hover is not flickering
- Also Im sure you wanted a transition so try this:

  #text {
    transition: letter-spacing 0.5s;
  }

```css
#text {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  transition: letter-spacing 0.5s;
}

#text:hover {
  letter-spacing: 10px
}
```

```html
<p id="text">sample text rotation</p>
```

You will probably need more block /width /spacing so it can get the right setup but thats all you...

Comment: This is a lot of overkill and will not fix the actual issue.

Comment: UX thinking my friend but yes generic is fine

Comment: Yeah this one doesn't fixe the issue.